# With the Google Sheets API, I can get the data from the table with the get method, but the append method gives an error

Tags: python, authentication, google-sheets, google-api, google-client

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
credentials=None
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID= '1nRVonS_Akp14vlzAiDlyH6mDRetS3bB62w1cfWZi***'
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

#GET
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                        range="Sayfa1!A1:A2").execute()
print(result)
aoa=["1"]
#APPEND
request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={"values":aoa}).execute()
```

When I run this code I'm getting this error:

> C:\Python39\python.exe
> C:/Users/seher/PycharmProjects/temizbirsayfa/main.py {'range':
> 'Sayfa1!A1:A2', 'majorDimension': 'ROWS', 'values': [['1'], ['5']]}
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\seher\PycharmProjects\temizbirsayfa\main.py", line 23, in
>
> request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="A1",
> valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
> body={"values":aoa}).execute()   File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient_helpers.py", line 134,
> in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 915, in
> execute
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting
> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1nRVonS_Akp14vlzAiDlyH6mDRetS3bB62w1cfWZi***/values/A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&alt=json
> returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller
> does not have permission">
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

It says that I don't have permission but I do because I can get the data from the sheet. So what is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Read permission is not the same as write permission. Maybe something around that.

Comment: Perhaps you only have permission to view the sheet but not edit it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I gave the edit permission and it fixed.